# How to use union just once with where command?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use a query in php with `where` command `where notifikasi = '1'` in the `2 tables`, but **I only see 1 table** that gets `where notifikasi = '1'`, **how can I make both my tables** get `where notifikasi = '1'`?

```
SELECT a.id_skd as idab,a.nl as nl1, a.aa as aa1,a.jp as jp1, a.syarat_lampiran as syarat_lampiran1,a.riwayat_kelola as riwayat_kelola1,a.notifikasi as notifikasi1 
FROM skd a
UNION ALL 
SELECT b.id_skb as idab, b.nl as nl1, b.aa as aa1, b.jp as jp1, b.syarat_lampiran as syarat_lampiran1,b.riwayat_kelola as riwayat_kelola1, b.notifikasi as notifikasi1 
FROM skb b  
WHERE notifikasi='1' 
ORDER BY riwayat_kelola1 DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to repeat the `WHERE` clause, it only applies to one `SELECT` query, not the whole `UNION`.

```
SELECT a.id_skd as idab,a.nl as nl1, a.aa as aa1,a.jp as jp1, a.syarat_lampiran as syarat_lampiran1,a.riwayat_kelola as riwayat_kelola1,a.notifikasi as notifikasi1 
FROM skd a
WHERE notifikasi = '1'
UNION ALL 
SELECT b.id_skb as idab, b.nl as nl1, b.aa as aa1, b.jp as jp1, b.syarat_lampiran as syarat_lampiran1,b.riwayat_kelola as riwayat_kelola1, b.notifikasi as notifikasi1 
FROM skb b  
WHERE notifikasi='1' 
ORDER BY riwayat_kelola1 DESC 
LIMIT 1
```